# Iframe blocks elements behind it

Tags: web-part, css, iframe

Trying to embed a chatbot in SharePoint online. We're doing that with an iframe through True Editor Web Part http://prntscr.com/m3br5p

The issue is that even when the bot is folded like in this preview, scrolling or clicking buttons behind its unfolded area are not possible 
folded: http://prntscr.com/m3brdk
unfolded: http://prntscr.com/m3brxu

We're also experiencing similar issues when trying to lightbox/popup certain things that we want to load. I wish we could have a layer on top of sharepoint where we could just do anything we want (being externally, no need to integrate) while keeping everything behind it in tact.

How should we deal with this?

Comment: contact the support team of the third party web part.

Comment: The SPFX webpart?

Comment: True Editor. What is that?

Comment: I am using this SPFX True editor webpart to make JS + iframes possible again > https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor I guess it is not them to blame that I am not succeeding in layering my iframe/chatbot